# Saving a varying-size 2D vector to a file

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm making an evolutionary simulation. Every creature has a pair of (x, y) coordinates. I want to save them each simulation cycle. I need to save the data to a file since it takes up a lot of memory in the later stages of the simulation. The problem is that both the lifetime of the creature and the number of creatures are varying. Some may die off, new ones may be born. The number of cycles isn't fixed, the simulation runs until I stop it. My current code goes something like this:

Main simulation loop:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Creature>> creatures;
// ... Spawning the creatures

while (running)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ConfigManager::Settings().numCreatures; i++)
    {
        creatures[i]->SimulateCycle();
    }

    // ... Code for handling the exit mechanism
}
```

Creature code:

```
std::ofstream file;

void Creature::SimulateCycle()
{
    CalculatePosition();

    // Save data to file in binary
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&posX), sizeof(posX));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&posY), sizeof(posY));
}
```

I'm currently just creating a new file for each creature, but that's not really feasible for a high number of creatures (2000+). What should I do?

P.S. As you can see, I don't literally have a "vector of vectors", I have a vector of Creatures and I save their position data to the corresponding file each cycle.

Comment: You might want to look at a library to help create a structured binary data file with efficient access. (HDF5 is one I'm familiar with, but I can't comment how it compares to others.)

Comment: More than some position you have to save some information abut the creature so that you can reconstruct.

Comment: I don't see why the code shown wouldn't work just as well when writing positions of all creatures to the same file. Just open and close the file outside of the loop over creatures (whereas now you apparently do it inside; though the shown code never so much as declares `file`, let alone open or close it).